# how to use double Quotes correctly?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

```
This form works in VB .NET

sendMsg = "<CStatus timestamp=""0"" " & _
                   "type=""login"" " & _
                   "cid = """ & cID & """ " & _
                   "key=""" & loginKey & """ />"
```

But i can't get it work in C#

```
sendMsg = "<CStatus timestamp=\"0\" 
                    type=\"login\" 
                    cid=\"" + cID + "\" 
                    key=\"" + loginKey + "\" />";
```

it does not give the same effect

I want this as an output:

```
<CStatus timestamp="0" type="login" cid="var_cid" key="var_key"/>;
```

is there any stringXml command in C# or another way to use double quotes in string?

Thank You!

---

Solved it with

```
 XmlTextWriter
```

Thanks to you all!

Comment: Use `String.Format` and `Verbatim Strings`.

Comment: I want to use double quotes in a String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the XElement and XAttribute classes which will work both in VB and C#:

```
string cID = "blah";
string loginKey = "foo";

var xml = new XElement("CStatus",
              new XAttribute("timestamp", "0"),
              new XAttribute("type", "login"),
              new XAttribute("cid", cID),
              new XAttribute("key", loginKey)
          );

string sendMsg = xml.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Embedded newlines are not supported for string literals in C#. Try:

```
sendMsg = "<CStatus timestamp=\"0\" " +
                    "type=\"login\" " +
                    "cid=\"" + cID + "\" " +
                    "key=\"" + loginKey + "\" />";
```

Your problem does not seem to be related to your use of quotes.

Comment: it gives as output: <CStatus timestamp=\"0\" type=\"login\" cid=\"cid\" key=\"key\" />

Comment: *What* gives as output? You haven't shown how you are writing the string. Perhaps the method you're using to write the string is re-escaping the quotes.

Comment: I dont use any method, i get it work in Vb .net but not in c#.

Comment: Are you looking at the debugger display perhaps? Maybe it's escaping the quotes for you. Try this: Print the *length* of your `sendMsg` string, and then count the characters. See whether your string contains just `"` or `\"` by counting characters.

Comment: I can debug the output it comes \" as an output

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "I can debug the output" means. How does the length of `sendMsg` compare to what you expect?

Comment: @Vural Acar: I tested Greg's code and the output is this: `<CStatus timestamp="0" type="login" cid="1" key="2" />` (replaced variables cID and loginKey by 1 and 2). So it's working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When using quotes in C#, you would escape them with the backslash `\"`, as you have tried.

However, when you are splitting your string across multiple lines, try the alternate path of marking the string with `@` and then double the quotes for proper escaping.

```
string theString = @"<CStatus timespamp=""0""
                              type=""login""
                     />"; // fill in the rest
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Format(@"<CStatus timestamp=""0""
                         type=""login""
                         cid=""{0}""
                         key=""{1}"" />", cID, loginKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways you can do this.

In the current way you're trying to do it, it won't work.  You're trying to put a newline into a constant string.  You'd have to rewrite it as:

```
sendMsg = "<CStatus timestamp=\"0\" " +
                "type=\"login\" " +
                "cid=\"" + cID + "\" " + 
                "key=\"" + loginKey + "\" />";
```

Notice the extra +'s at the end of every line and how each line is its own string constant.

I think it might be easier to just use String.Format in this case:

```
sendMsg = String.Format("<CStatus timestamp=\"0\" type=\"login\" cid=\"{0}\" key=\"{1}\" />",
              cID, loginKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are escaped like this in c#: `\"` for example, `timestamp="0"`  with double quotes should be `timestamp=\"\"0\"\"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes as you do in vb, but start your string definition whith @

```
string myString = @"<xml attribute=""my attribute""/>";
```

You can check this link to see other methods to scape double quotes: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx

Comment: I am still reading the article, i'll answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

```
sendMsg = "<CStatus timestamp=\"0\" " +  
                    "type=\"login\" " + 
                    "cid=\"" + cID + "\" +
                    "key=\"" + loginKey + "\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sendMsg = @"<CStatus timestamp=""0"" type=""login"" cid=""" + cID + """ key=""" + loginKey + """ />";
```

Answer (score 0):

As Greg Hewgill says, you have newlines in your strings in the c# version.

You really should use String.Format here, but to answer your question, your code should look like:

```
sendMsg = "<CStatus timestamp=\"0\"  + 
                    "type=\"login\"" + 
                    "cid=\"" + cID + "\"" + 
                    "key=\"" + loginKey + "\" />";
```

As a String.Format call, it would be:

```
sendMsg = String.Format(@"<CStatus timestamp=""{0}"" 
         type=""{1}"" 
         cid=""{2}"" 
         key=""{3}""/>", 0, login, cID, loginKey );
```

Comment: For quotes in literal strings, you need to use two quote signs.  Otherwise, it will think it's the end of the opened literal string.